# Asp repeater accessing each line from an sql datasource

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a repeater that on itemdatabound i want to access the row in the sqldatasource so i can get the id of an item.

I cant use hidden fields to do this so are there any other options? Thanks to all

Comment: what did you try? how does your markup look like? if you can't use hidden, what about labels or literals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ItemDataBound try:

```
((DataRowView)e.Item.DataItem)["YourKey"]
```

DataItem is your bound item, be it a custom class or a data row for example. This depends on how you are binding it but you didn't specify.

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this in the ItemDataBound event:

```
if (Repeater1.DataSource != null)
{
    int ID = ((DataTable)Repeater1.DataSource).Rows[e.Item.ItemIndex].Field<int>("ID");
}
```

Or this might work too:

```
int ID = (int)((DataRowView)e.Item.DataItem)["ID"];
```

Comment: Sorry James, Adam just bet you too it. Thanks though this would have worked also

Comment: Then, hook him up with a +1. :)

Comment: @Wesley Skeen: No worries. You got it working, which is what matters.